# How do you create a list of all the days in the month using a non recursive approach? (Recursive Sample Provided)

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2012

I am interested in the days of the current month. The following code is how I would do this recursively:

```
WITH AllMonthDays as (
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM AllMonthDays WHERE n + 1 <= DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE())) 
)

SELECT 
    datefromparts(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), n) as dates
FROM AllMonthDays;
```

I appreciate the above may not be optimal. But my question here is how would I achieve the above non recursively and not hard coding any dates.

EDIT: Removed CAST to VCHAR Entirely, thanks to the suggestion from 'Gordon Linoff'.

Comment: Use while loop(s)? Set variables to calculate first and last days of the current month.  Not sure why you wouldn't use the recursion though...  or use dateadd and subtract/add until you get a different month.  writing each day to a temp table and then select from it...

Comment: if this is currently working for you I suggest you ask this question at [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: MAXRECURSION is set to 100 - Unless changed. Which if this code were to be expanded upon, would be limited to just over three months. Given I can not guarentee I will have permission to change this setting in another environment, I thus have asked the question of how to write this using a non recursive approach. I do not believe 'Code Review' is required as this is a question. Maybe I should have excluded how far I have got with my answer.

Comment: I agree with @xQbert. You could easily use a while loop and add the values to a table, but recursion allows you to avoid loops. The advantage of a table is that you could fill it once and use the values repeatedly without recalculating them, but I doubt that would be any more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, a table called `master..spt_values` is used for this purpose.  It is rather undocumented but generally available.  Actually, any table with at least 31 rows can be used.

So, to generate the numbers and construct the date:

```
with n as (
      select top 31 row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), n.n) as thedate
from n
where n.n <= day(eomonth(getdate()));
```

Note:  `datefromparts()` is a very convenient way to construct a date.  Also, when you use `varchar` in SQL Server, *always* include a length.  The default varies by context and finding bugs caused by this problem can be quite difficult.

Comment: Thank you for this. The improvements to my original code are greatly appreciated as well .